# validar que se haya digitado numeros y puntos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cómo comprobar si un usuario digitó en uno de varios input de la misma clase, solo caracteres caracteres del 0 al 9 y puntos... no que me permita solo digitar esos valores si no que al digitar valide con el evento Keyup

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.input_valores_provisionales').keyup(
    function()
    { 
      $(".input_valores_provisionales").each(
        function()
        {

        }
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: No necesitas el .each interno porque .keyup vailidara cada input individualmente.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".input_valores_provisionales").keypress(function(event) {
  var c = event.keyCode || event.which,
  key = String.fromCharCode(c),
  chars = "0123456789."
  return chars.search(key) !== -1
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Con el evento `keypress` lo puedes manejar mejor y con las propiedades `keyCode` o `which` del evento (depende del navegador) conjunto con la función `String.fromCharCode`.

Te aconsejo que juntes en un string todos los caracteres permitidos y compruebes si el caracter ingresado se encuentra en tal string. Retornando `false` en el método `keydown()` bloqueas la acción de escritura.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación pero ¿podrías proporcionar un ejemplo con código?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar un `input` para que solo acepte valores numéricos con el evento `onkeydown` este permite aceptar o rechazar el valor antes que este sea cargado al `input`.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional de como hacerlo.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.isNumber').on("keydown", function(e) {
   if(e.key.length == 1 && e.key != "." && isNaN(e.key))
    return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="isNumber">
```

Answer (score -1):

te dejo el codigo:

```
<input type="text" class="input-number" value="" />
```

el javascript:

```
$('.input-number').on('input', function () { 
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades suerte !!